# Scrolling and Tooltip doesn't work with Telerik RadGrid

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik-grid

I found a strange problem with Telerik RadGrid.

I have used paging with scrolling in it, and in that i have implemented the tool tip edit. But tool tip only appear for the data in first grid, for rest of the data tool tip disappears.

Help me with this..

Comment: I got reply from Telerik team that there is no work around for this, both features are not possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature is not possbile with telerik grid. I got this reply from telerik team..

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 2 years late, but for anyone still running into this problem (like I was), here is what I used as my workaround.

In your RadGrid's ItemDataBound method, create a Label, set its Text and Tooltip to whatever you want, and then add it as a control to whichever cells need tooltips. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub WeeklyDataGrid_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles WeeklyDataGrid.ItemDataBound
     If e.Item.ItemType = GridItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = GridItemType.AlternatingItem Then
          Dim tooltip As New Label
          tooltip.Text = drv("JobNumber").ToString.Trim
          tooltip.ToolTip = drv("ProjectName").ToString.Trim
          e.Item.Cells(0).Controls.Add(tooltip)
     End If
End Sub
```

Works perfectly for me.